# yq: Add new value to list in alphabetical order

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a simple yaml file called `foo.yaml`

```yaml
foo:
 - a
 - c
bar:
 - foo: bar
   foo2: bar2
```

I'm trying to add a new value (`b`) to `foo`, in alphabetical order. I can add the value with `+=`, but it doesn't get alphabatized

```
$ yq '.foo += "b"' foo.yaml

foo:
  - a
  - c
  - b
bar:
  - foo: bar
    foo2: bar2
```

If I use `+` I can use `sort`, but I only get the raw values. e.g.:

```bash
$ yq '.foo + "b" | sort()' foo.yaml

- a
- b
- c
```

I tried to set this into a bash variable and then use it with `=`, but it appears as a multi-line text

```bash
$ variable=$(yq '.foo + "b" | sort()' foo.yaml)

$ yq ".foo = \"$variable\"" foo.yaml

foo: |-
  - a
  - b
  - c
bar:
  - foo: bar
    foo2: bar2
```

Is there an easier way to insert a new value into `foo` alphabetically, while keeping the rest of the yaml in tact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are getting the raw values is that you've told `yq` to traverse into 'foo'. Instead try:

```bash
yq '.foo = (.foo + "b" | sort)' file.yaml
```

yields:

```yaml
foo:
  - a
  - b
  - c
bar:
  - foo: bar
    foo2: bar2
```

Explanation:

- you need to update the entry in 'foo'
- then, in brackets, set the new value. Normally you can use +=, but because you want to sort I've used '='

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: Oh, and the reason the second way put everything in a string, is because you have quotes around $variable. If you needed to do something like that, use the "env" operator https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators